# Regular expression to capture the smallest element in an XML tree

Tags: regex, go

Consider the example program below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var re = regexp.MustCompile(`<a>.*?<b>foobar</b>.*?</a>`)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(re.FindString("<a><a><b>foobar</b></a></a>"))
}
```

Here, given the input `<a><a><b>foobar</b></a></a>`, I want to extract `<a><b>foobar</b></a>`, that is the smallest XML element of type `a` that contains the expected string `<b>foobar</b>`. However, when I run it, I get

```
> go run main.go
<a><a><b>foobar</b></a>
```

That is, it picks up an unwanted `<a>` at the beginning as well. Apparently the non-greedy `.*?` doesn't prevent it from matching two `<a>`s; can anyone explain why and suggest an alternative?

Comment: Do you expect a single match, or multiple matches? In the former case, you can use `.*(<a>.*?<b>foobar</b>.*?</a>)`, and grab Group 1 value. It extracts the last match, but if you only expect one single match in a string, it will do the job (though it is not efficient). If you expect multiple matches, it is not possible since Go regexp does not allow lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

To convert Wiktor's comment into an answer, the following program,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var re = regexp.MustCompile(`.*(<a>.*?<b>foobar</b>.*?</a>)`)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(re.FindStringSubmatch("<a><a><b>foobar</b></a></a>")[1])
}
```

returns the desired result,

```
> go run main.go
<a><b>foobar</b></a>
```

(I indeed only expect one match).